# Calculate seasonal precipitation and temperature from CRU TS 4.05 in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, netcdf, multi-band, climate

The Goal: To calculate the average spring (Mar-Apr-May) and summer (Jun-Jul-Aug) precipitation and temperature for a series of specific, discrete locations. These points represent sites (I'm an archaeologist), and I'm using the CRU TS 4.05 data (1901-2020) as a modern climatic proxy given its long-term nature. I've already managed to get the NetCDF into GIS as a multiband raster, which I've clipped down to my areas of interest, so what I need now is to extract the appropriate bands (representing the months/seasons I need) and run some raster calculations on these.

The Problem: Since I'm using the 1901-2020 data, there are 1440 bands in my raster (TIF) (12 months x 120 years). Selecting the bands I want manually will not only take ages, it's prone to errors.

How can I implement some kind of automatic selection of bands corresponding to the two sets of months I want (spring: MAM, or 3, 4, 5; and summer: JJA, or 6, 7, 8) that can be fast and error-free? I have not figured out how to see the data in a tabular form yet, other than at specific point locations.

The Limitations: I'm pretty good in GIS (good ArcGIS Pro, capable in QGIS), but I don't use R and can't invest in learning that from scratch right now. I don't know Python, though if someone has such code and can explain step-by-step how to add and modify it in an ArcGIS Pro toolbox I could manage that.

One idea I had was to use the time properties in the "pre_Layer" generated by the "Make " tool. There seem to be ways to define a step interval and offset it here, for example choosing March out of the whole set (offset 3, time interval 12 months), though when I tried it still shows 1440 bands in properties, instead of the expected 120.... anyone know better how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Often first steps to automation, without any code in ESRI software is learning to use modelbuilder. You would use an iterator to step through layers/values and use that to help extract out specific layers from your raster stack. I would suggest you explore the help file on the topic [modelbuilder](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder-.htm), it will open up a whole new world to automating data processing to avoid the often tedious and error prone manual approach.

There are also professional training courses you could attend to fast track you into the subject.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I've used model builder in the past (back in ArcMap before I migrated to ArcGIS Pro), so I'm generally familiar with it and could - theoretically - figure something out in there. Though I was kind of hoping someone, somewhere had already worked out how to pull specific bands out of the 1000+ in there, and could share a workflow or specific process. I can't be the first person wanting to do this with CRU TS data...

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS PRO is capable of reading NETCDF files, and I just learned that a couple of days ago, you need to add a multidimensional layer (then add your NETCDF file) to your project and that's it. Then use aggregate multidimensional Raster; using this tool you can define the analysis interval, let's say monthly or yearly; since your NTCDF files include time information AGPro should read those times. I'm still learning since I need an hourly average, but monthly is included in the Aggregate multidimensional Raster tool.